# How to work on a new Theme for a site while still keeping the old Theme live

Tags: themes

I have a WordPress.org site. I am planning to use a new theme for the site. I have Installed the template and it is currently under the Themes folder.

The old theme is currently active. I would like to work on the new template and keep the old template active.

Once I finish working on the new theme, I would then like to make that active.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The terms _**template**_ and _**theme**_have specific meanings within WordPress. A theme is a collection of files and templates that are used to display content.

You can create a new template within a theme, as long as the template does not have the same name as a current template. The best, safest and most appropriate approach is to develop and edit the template in an IDE (e.g. Notepad++, Coda) and not in the theme editor. See these codex links for a thorough explanation of themes and templates

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes
https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Comment: @RayMitchell Yes, what I meant was a theme. I modified the question accordingly. Thanks. But if we edit the template in notepad , how can we do a preview to see how it looks?

Comment: If you have FTP access to the site, you can upload your edited template file and add it to the appropriate folder in your theme. Regarding previewing a theme, as Industrial Themes suggested you can use a theme switching plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-switcha/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a theme tester plugin to test your theme only for admin user while all other users continue to use the old theme. Here are two such plugins:

[Theme Test Drive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/)

[WP Theme Test](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-theme-test/)

Please note the officially supported version of WordPress each of those plugins works with. Also, [here is an article](https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/customizing-wordpress-themes/) with further resources on how to test themes before they're live and public-facing.

Answer (score -1):

You could clone (e.g. with [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)) your website under a subdomain, work safely on the clone and go back to live site with all changes when you are happy.